# Proof of geodesic has constant speed

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

So I'm working with differential geometry. So my book claim that 
*"any geodesic has constant speed"*.

And the proof is left as an exercise and I found the exercise in the book.

**Exercise:** *"Prove that any geodesic has constant speed and so a very simple unit-speed reparametrization."*

I know the definition of geodesic, but I don't know how to work it out.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** The definition,

"Let $\gamma$ be a curve on a surface $\textbf{S}$. Then the curve is called a $\textit{geodesic}$ if $\ddot{\gamma}$ is zero or orthogonal to the tangent plane of the surface at the point $\gamma$."

Comment: "I know the definition of geodesic", you should provide the definition that you are working with.

Comment: I added it to the question above.

Comment: Okay, I’ve edited my answer to remove the more general context.

Answer (score 3):

Since geodesics have acceleration normal to the surface, the acceleration is also normal to the velocity (which is *tangent* to the surface). So, if our curve is $\alpha,$ then $\alpha'\cdot\alpha''=0.$ Hence, $$0=2\alpha'\cdot\alpha''=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\|\alpha'\|^2\right).$$

Comment: So this is actually the proof or? 

The last part of the exercise "and so a very simple unit-speed reparametrization." does not make sense for me, how does it work?

Comment: That's the entire proof that the speed is constant. Regarding the parameterization question, if $\|\alpha'\|=c,$ then you can simply reparameterize via $\beta(s)=\alpha(s/c)$ (which now has unit speed).